# File doesn't exist after I try and write to it IOS

Tags: ios, ios5

I have an existing file and I want to delete it's content and then write to it again but only by appending it line by line. Here is my code not sure why it's not working :

```
if ([filemgr removeItemAtPath: fileName error: NULL]  == YES){
        NSLog (@"Remove successful");
    }
    else{
        NSLog (@"Remove failed");
    }

    NSString *cachePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",fileName];
    NSFileHandle *fileHandler = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:cachePath];
    BOOL isFirst = NO;

    for(id entry in serializedObjects){
        NSString *sectionName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"!%@\n", entry];
        [fileHandler writeData:[sectionName dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        if (!isFirst) {
            [fileHandler seekToEndOfFile];
            isFirst = YES;
        }

        NSArray *list = [serializedObjects objectForKey:entry];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++) {
            NSString *line = [[list objectAtIndex:i] stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
            [fileHandler writeData:[line dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        }

        [fileHandler writeData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @"~\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

[fileHandler closeFile];
```

My idea was to write the first line to the file and append the others. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

After this method has completed I see no errors but the file which I'm trying to write to doesn't exist after I manually check.

Comment: Why not try and first build the string completely and then write to file? Seems like less writing to disc and a little less complicated. That for starters.

Comment: @London but writing big string can be memory intensive

Comment: And your approach is processing intensive probably, guess it's a tradeoff, somewhat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file handle writes to the I/O buffer which will not instantly write to disk.  Because io is slow this is efficiency built into file handle objects.  To ensure it writes to disk you must flush the io buffer using synchronizeFile.  You also need to call closeFile when you are done with the file handle (which will also synchronize, so the synchronize is optional).

Comment: I've already got file handler close file just forgot to include it in this question. What exactly must I do? How do I flush the io buffer? how do I fix this code?

Comment: The method is called synchronizeFile